# Convert & store String into currency values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have a String and i need to convert it into Currency format in RUBY and
verify whether it matches to the expected.

```
String = "$6,178.50 USD / 22,693.01 AED"
```

I want to split it into 2 different variables like

```
usa_price = $6,178.50

aed_price = 22,693.01
```

`expected_output= $6,178.50 * 3.67 = 22,693.01` (should match value in AED)

I tried doing gsub/scan and im confused now, what's the best way to
achieve this in Ruby!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure that first number is USD and second number is AED and the order won't change then:

```
str = "$6,178.50 USD / 22,693.01 AED"

usa_price, aed_price = str.scan(/\d{1,2}?,?\d{1,3}\.\d{2}/)

#=> usa_price = 6,178.50, aed_price = 22,693.01
```

Comment: Will this solution work for non-thousand dollar amounts, i.e. $178.50?

Comment: How about amounts in the hundreds of thousands?

Comment: Or in the millions, or billions, or trillions, or quadrillions, or quintillions, or sextillions, or septillions, or octillions... basically, any unit listed here: https://github.com/radar/humanize/blob/master/lib/lots.rb

Comment: The point I'm trying to (perhaps excessively) make is that parsing money amounts with regexes is bad and should not be attempted at all. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: I agree that your solution is best, but don't agree that regexes should never be used to parse money. In fact, the money gem uses regexes to parse money: https://github.com/collectiveidea/money/blob/master/lib/money/core_extensions.rb#L48

Answer (score 7):

I would split on the `/` and then use the [`money`](http://money.rubyforge.org/) gem to parse the amounts out, like this:

```
require 'money'
amounts = "$6,178.50 USD / 22,693.01 AED".split("/")
amounts.map! { |amount| Money.parse(amount) }
```

Then, because they're now `Money` objects, you can do money things with them:

```
>> amounts.first.format
=> "$6,178.50"
```